# Does continuous extension exists under specific conditions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was unable to solve this problem asked in my exam of Topology and need help.

> True or False :  Does A continuous function on $\mathbb{Q} $ Intersection [0, 1] can be extended to a continuous function on [0, 1] .

I couldn't think of what theorem or counterexample I should use and hence I am posting here.

Any help please.

Comment: Are you asking if a continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ can *always* be extended to a continuous function on $[0,1]$, or if there are continuous functions on this domain that are not continuous on $[0,1]$?

Comment: @ccroth  if a continuous function f on Q∩[0,1] can be extended to a continuous function on [0,1]. Is this statement true or false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What is the simplest function you can think of that blows up at $1/\sqrt 2?$

Comment: I was thinking $1/(x-1/\sqrt 2).$

Comment: Can you please help me with this question  also if you have some spare time. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3732610/proof-of-countable-additive-property-of-lebesgue-integrable-functions