# A question in proof theorem 12.9 of Tom M Apostol ( Mathematical Analysis)

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

While self studying Mathematical Analysis from Tom M Apostol, I am unable to deduce a statement in following proof :
[image]

> Question: I am unable to deduce how to prove existance of $\delta$  such that x+tu belongs to S  for all real t in that interval in line 1.

I tried using defination of L(x, y) and that L(x, y) belongs to S and also putting  u = x-y in defination of L(x, y)  but couldn't prove it .

Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for $0 \leq t \leq 1$ we have $x+tu=x+t(y-x)=ty+(1-t) x$. This lies in $L(x,y) \subseteq S$. Now, for $-\delta <t<0$ we have $|(x+tu) -x|\leq \delta |y-x|$. Since $x \in S$  and $S$ is open it follows that $x+tu \in S$ provided $\delta >0$ is sufficiently small. A similar argument works for  $1 <t <1+\delta$.

You have to choose $\delta$ such that $B(x,\delta |y-x|) \subset S$ and $B(y,\delta |y-x|) \subset S$

Comment: just after this section Apostol gave some examples, in one of the examples he wrote that if we apply Cauchy Schwartz inequality to ( 23) with ||a||=1 , we will get -> ||f(y) -f(x) || $\leq$ || f'(z) (y-x) || . But I am unable to understand how Cauchy Schwartz inequality yields this? I don't think this question should be asked separately, so I am asking you here. Can you please tell

Comment: I think you didn't covered the case when 0< $\delta$ <1 ?

Comment: @user795826 We are suposed to prove the inequality for $-\delta <t <1+\delta$ and I am splitting the proof into the cases $-\delta <t <0, 0 \leq t \leq 1$ and $1<t<1+\delta$. That covers all cases.

Comment: I got it!! Thanks!!

Comment: can you please answer the question asked in 1 st comment? Or you think I should ask it separately.

Comment: @user795826 MVT applied to $t \to f(ty+(1-t)x)$ shows that $f(y)-f(x)=f'(z)(y-x)$ for some $z$. Hence $\|f(y)-f(x)\| = \|f'(z)(y-x)\|$. I don't think C-S inequality is required here. But you can use C-S inequality to see that $\|f(y)-f(x)\| = \|f'(z)\| \|(y-x)\|$.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking the same. Thank you!!

Comment: There is another question about Lebesgue Measure which no one has answered. If you are interested and have some spare time can you please help me with that?   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3732610/proof-of-countable-additive-property-of-lebesgue-integrable-functions