# Proving mean value theorem in case of vector valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Let $f:U\to \mathbb R^n$ be differentiable on an open subset $U\subset \mathbb R^m$. Suppose that $a,b\in U$ are such that the set $L:=\{a+(b-a)t: t\in [0,1]\}\subset U.$ Then, the following holds: $\|f(b)-f(a)\|\le \sup_{z\in L}\|Df_z\|_{\text{op}}\,\|b-a\|$, where op stands for the operator norm.

**Proof:**  If $f(b)=f(a)$, then there is nothing to prove so assume that $f(b)\ne f(a)$. Define $u:=f(b)-f(a)$ and $g(t):=u\cdot f(a+t(b-a)), t\in [0,1]$ and $\cdot$ in definition of $g$ is the usual dot product. $g$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ and continuous on $[0,1]$.  So by mean value theorem, there exists a $\rho\in (0,1)$ such that $$g(1)-g(0)=g'(\rho)=u\cdot \color{blue}{f'(a+\rho(b-a); b-a)}=u\cdot (f(b)-f(a))\tag 1$$

The blue colored term in $(1)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at $a+\rho(b-a)$ along $b-a$. Define $\alpha(t):=a+t(b-a)$. It follows by $(1)$ that $$u\cdot (f(b)-f(a))=u\cdot Df_{\alpha(\rho)}(b-a)\tag 2$$
It follows by $(2)$ that $\|u\|^2=\|u\cdot Df_{\alpha(\rho)}(b-a)\|\le\|u\|\,\|Df_{\alpha(\rho)}\|_{\text{op}}\, \|b-a\|\tag 3$
The desired inequality follows by $(3)$.

Explanation for:

Para before $(1)$: I used the following lemma: If $h:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^n$ is a function such that $\lim_{x\to a} h(x)$ exists for some $a$, then for any $u\in \mathbb R^n$, $\lim_{x\to a} u\cdot h(x)=u\cdot (\lim_{x\to a}h(x)).$

$(3)$: For any linear map $T:\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^n$, $\|Tx\|\le \|T\|_{\text{op}}\,\|x\|$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^m$.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

Comment: `$\cdot$` gets a raised dot product dot.

Comment: Are $a,b$ supposed to live on this line $L$? Or are they supposed to be $x,y$?

Comment: @FShrike: I've edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: @Randall: I've edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: I guess in the title you mean "vector valued" instead of "multi valued"?!

Comment: @PhoemueX: Yes, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: You switch throughout between $a,b$ and $x,y$. but looks right

Comment: @CalvinKhor: Thanks for the review. Please help me understand why Apostol considers  $g$ in $(-\delta, 1+\delta)$ for a suitable $\delta>0$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3737408/a-question-in-proof-theorem-12-9-of-tom-m-apostol-mathematical-analysis).

Comment: I don't know. Clearly Apostol gets differentiability at $\theta=0,1$ as well but I cant see why this is important

Comment: Thanks a lot @CalvinKhor. :)

Comment: Oh, if $Df$ doesnt exist at the endpoints then I guess $\sup_{z\in L} \|Df_z\|_{op}$ might be hard to define...

Comment: @CalvinKhor: $Df$ exists on bigger set $U$ (which properly contains $L$). And I think no harm is done even if $\sup_{z\in L}\|Df_z\|_{op}$ is taken to $+\infty$. For, in that case the statement is trivially true.

Comment: .......yea OK i revert to not understanding Apostol at all